# How to initialize a two-dimentional array in Swift 2?

Tags: arrays, swift2

Is there a single line equivalent for this Java code used to create a 2d array:

```
cells = new Cell[width][height];
```

in **Swift 2.0**?

Looking at various solutions here in Stack Overflow I have ended up with a multi-line monster of:

```
self.cells = [[Cell]]()
for (var col=0; col<height; col++){
    var newColumn = Array<Cell>.init(count: width, repeatedValue: Cell(x: 0,y: 0))
    self.cells.append(newColumn);
}
```

which creates an empty array for me. But I am quite sure that's not the right solution, just a duct tape kind of workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use a loop:

```
let inner = Array<Cell>(count: width, repeatedValue: Cell(x: 0,y: 0))
let cells = Array<[Cell]>(count: height, repeatedValue: inner)
```

It could be a one-liner of course:

```
let cells = Array<[Cell]>(count: height, repeatedValue: Array<Cell>(count: width, repeatedValue: Cell(x: 0,y: 0)))
```

But I prefer having separate statements for readability.

Comment: indeed the one liner is a mammoth size of statement :) will use the neat two lines version